# Strongly-typed XML native database with XSD support

Tags: java, xml, database, xsd, native

I am looking for a Java-based implementation of an XML native database, which exploits XML schema to provide strongly typed operations and checks over the stored data. Does anyone is aware of such a database?

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but you may fine it interesting anyway: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home

Comment: http://xml.apache.org/xindice/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic (i work there) offers a native XML database that provides XML Schema support - scale, performance, enterprise ready. It is *not* written in Java:
developer.marklogic.com/products

eXist is an open source xml database written in java. however, i don't know the degree of XML Schema support:
exist.sourceforge.net/